# Looping through and getting frequency of all the elements in an array

Tags: javascript

I am looping through an array which is `[2,2,"2","2",4,4]` so i am calulating frequency of each elements here and then storing the element as key in object and its frequency as a value of that corresponding key.

So below is the code for that

```
let countobjet={},r=[]
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  let count=0

  for(j=0;j<array.length;j++){
    if(array[i]===array[j]){count++ 

  }
  }
countobjet[array[i]]=count
}
console.log(countobjet)
```

Now console.log here gives

> {2: 2, 4: 2}

what i want was

> {2:2,2:2,4:2}

as i have two "2" of type string and two 2 of type number, i want to treat them as seperate key in the object cause i have to calulate its frequency seperately considering their type

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen nope mate, still getting same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really do this with an object, since all keys of objects either strings or symbols. A non-string or non-symbol key would be converted to a string instead:

```js
const obj = {};

obj["42"] = 1;
obj[42] = 2;

console.log(obj)
```

If you want to keep the type intact, you can use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which does not have this limitation for its keys:

```js
const array = [2,2,"2","2",4,4];

let countobjet = new Map(),
  r = []
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  let count = 0

  for (j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    if (array[i] === array[j]) {
      count++
    }
  }
  countobjet.set(array[i], count)
}

for(let [key, value] of countobjet.entries()) {
  console.log(`For key ${key} of type ${typeof key}, count is: ${value}`)
}

console.log(Array.from(countobjet.entries()));
```

Comment: @VLAZ and is there any way now i can convert this object i had into array ? A normal object would jus take Object.entries(countobjet) but what about this ?

Comment: @Ratnabh if you do `Array.from(countobjet)` or `[...countobjet]` you would get the same kind of array which contains key-value pairs that `Object.entries()` produces. For a Map, the `entries` method returns an iterator, so it just needs to be turned to an array.

Comment: just one more stuff if i had an simple object i loop it through like let max=Object.keys(obj).filter(k=>obj[k]===Math.max(...Object.values(obj))) to find the key with max value so how would i do it in here ?with new Map() object?

Comment: @Ratnabhkumarrai you can do pretty much the same thing but the map just returns iterators for keys/values, so you need to convert to array `[...map.keys()].filter(k => map.get(k) === Math.max(...map.values()))`

Answer (score 2):

> The Object keys in javascript behave like "strings". Also, in an
>   object two keys cannot be the same.

This is the reason why your code is not working.

In object literal terms, `b` is a property.  Properties are either strings or [symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) in JavaScript, although when defining the property name inside an object literal you may omit the string delimiters.

```
for (key in a) {
    alert(typeof key);
    //-> "string"
}
```

Comment: You may transform the keys into something like Number_2 and String_2 to differentiate between two keys. Please upvote & accept the answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of an object. Objects coerce keys into strings. Maps can use objects or primitives.

```js
const frequencies = arr =>
  arr.reduce((m, e) => m.set(e, (m.get(e) || 0) + 1), new Map())

const data = [2, 2, '2', '2', 4, 4]

const result = frequencies(data)

console.log(result) // Map { 2 => 2, '2' => 2, 4 => 2 }
```

If you have to use an object you could do something like the next two examples.

You can make a key by combining type and value:

```js
const key = x => `${typeof x} ${x}`

const frequencies = arr =>
  arr.reduce(
    (o, e) => ({
      ...o,
      [key(e)]: (o[key(e)] || 0) + 1,
    }),
    {}
  )

const data = [2, 2, '2', '2', 4, 4]

const result = frequencies(data)

console.log(result)
```

Or, nest the frequency counts in type properties:

```js
const frequencies = arr =>
  arr.reduce((o, e) => {
    const type = typeof e
    o[type] = o[type] || {}
    o[type][e] = (o[type][e] || 0) + 1
    return o
  }, {})

const data = [2, 2, '2', '2', 4, 4]

const result = frequencies(data)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the key is "2" it will be overridden for the occurrences on String and number.

You can check the occurrences as follow

```js
let countobjet = {};
let array = [2, 2, "2", "2", 4, 4];

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let count = 0

    for (j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (typeof array[i] === 'string' && typeof array[j] === 'string'
            && array[i] === array[j]) {
            count++;
        } else if (typeof array[i] === 'number' && typeof array[j] === 'number'
            && array[i] === array[j]) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (typeof array[i] === 'string')
        countobjet[array[i] + '_str'] = count;
    else
        countobjet[array[i]] = count;
}
console.log(countobjet)
```

[image]